# how to fetch table field in other field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a cart and subcategory model. I want to fetch the price of the service. How I fetch the price of service in the price field.
I want to fetch price of service in the price field.

[image]

***Here is my models.py***

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    id_parent = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Cart(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', related_name="carts", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    service = models.ForeignKey('accounts.SubCategory',null=True,  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    price = models.ForeignKey('accounts.SubCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, related_name='subprice')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.price.price)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you clear, you just want to get `price` of `SubCategory` attached to `Cart`. If so, you don't need to add `price` field to `Cart` model to get `SubCategory` price.

You can just define `price` property on `Cart` model like this and use it in admin like a regular field:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', related_name="carts", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    service = models.ForeignKey('accounts.SubCategory',null=True,  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    

    @property
    def price(self):
        if self.service:
             return self.service.price
        
        return None
    
    @property
    def total(self):
        if self.service:
             return self.service.price * self.quantity

        return None

    def __str__(self):
        if self.price:
            return str(self.price)
        
        return "Can't show price with no service selected"
```

Answer (score 0):

You would not need to select a value for price since it's derived from the service you selected.

```py
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    id_parent = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', related_name="carts", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    service = models.ForeignKey('accounts.SubCategory',null=True,  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.service.price)  # if you want just the price of the single service

    @property
    def total_price(self):
        if self.service is not None:
            return self.service.price * self.quantity
        return 0


service = SubCategory(name="Help with Django", price=5)
aCart = Cart(user=1, quantity=2, service=service)
print(aCart.total_price)  # 10
```

Comment: it returns the error     AttributeError at /admin/category/cart/
'Cart' object has no attribute 'price'

Comment: rename the property method 'total_price' to 'price'.